# Linking a chart series' name to a range through VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, charts

I would like to link the chart series' name to a range on my worksheet, but not the whole string in that range. For example, instead of linking the name to a cell that contains "201601", I want the series name to be 2016. I tried using Left(cell,4) while assigning the name but it gives me an error.

Current VBA code

```
Sub changeLinks()
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Left(" & Range("P18").Address(, , , True) & ",4)"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Left(" & Range("I18").Address(, , , True) & ",4)"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=Left(" & Range("B18").Address(, , , True) & ",4)"
Next i    
End Sub
```

How can I change my code to do this?

Comment: Can you post your VBA that you currently have so we can attempt to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `SeriesCollection.Name`, what Excel is doing is updating the `SERIES()` function that defines the series. `SERIES()` cannot accept functions for arguments. It can only accept a range, named range, or string argument.

You'll need to do this in two steps, like this:

```
Sub changeLinks()
Dim i&
Dim name1$, name2$, name3$

name1 = Left(Range("P18").Value, 4)
name2 = Left(Range("I18").Value, 4)
name3 = Left(Range("B18").Value, 4)

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = name1
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = name2
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = name3
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this is it makes the series' name static. If I change the value in the cell, the chart does not update as well. I have to change about 100 graphs with 3 series each, which is why I want to do this on VBA. But after that, I'll just update the cell values so the charts should be dynamic

Comment: @rblade use an event procedure to run the macro whenever those cells are changed, or use another range that uses formulas to get the name you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the formula into another cell. For example, in P17, put this formula:

`=LEFT(P18,4)`

Then use P17 as the range containing the series name (in the Select Data dialog). When P18 changes, the formula in P17 will change, and so will the series name in the chart.